# Danfoss BD2.5 on 12V starting problem. Good signal on only one gate of both driving MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet

[image: sinus on sensing coil µPpin3/connector WT in 180° of crankshasignal yell µPpin3-grn gate2s][image: tentative diagram][image]

The winding resistances are OK, not shorted to ground. One of 3 compressor coils is 3.6 ohms (should be 3.5). Driver coil resistances is 0.2 ohm instead of the normal 0.3. Compressor turns 1/2 turn or less. I don't have a schematic.

I added some details on gate signals

- Yellow is g1
- Green is g2

Signal at µP is equal as at gate itself. MOSFET drains are connected to 2 coils with 0.2 (0.3) ohm resistance (BL and ZW marked connectors). A third coil has 3.5 ohm (marked WT). The 'Brn' connector (on the +) is common to all 3 coils. Is this motor BEMF controlled?[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Since you traced all this, you pretty much are able to draw a schematic from it. Is the board toasty or is it coated in some brown varnish?

Comment: no toasting. Only varnish!. in order to draw a real schematic  I still have to desolder some components since I cannot follow all cupper traces..

Comment: when I displace the rotor of the compressor, the shorting of cryostat provokes 1/2 turn or less (1 time). The signal repeats always after beeing interrupted shortly.

Comment: Should be fixable. Can you add what oscilloscope trace is what signal to your question?

Comment: joined = gate signals: yellow is g1; green is g2; (signal sampled at µP is equal as at gate itself.)

Comment: Does someone know something about the input signals influencing the generation of the gate signals?

Comment: Any progress on drawing a schematic?

Comment: Nobody knows what the input to the µP should be???

Comment: Again, a schematic with part numbers are vital to get help. Help us help you help us all.

Comment: i added a diagram...

Comment: On the white connector going to the sensing coil I see in half of the crankshaft positions (180° present and 180° not present) a 150Khz sine 8.5Vpp. When I try to start by shorting CT (cryostat),  I see periods of 1 seconds with gate pulses and the sensing signal as mentioned above. Then 1 second nothing. This repeats. I see the crackshaft move 10° from the same position but not turning.

Comment: When I edit my post I cannot add more pictures...

Comment: What could be the function of D10-C7-R11-R9-R10 for the µP??

Comment: Certainly getting somewhere! If you click on edit, please add all vital information into the original question as opposed to in comments, then click on the schematic symbol. Here you can draw a clean schematic. What's the model number of the IC in the middle? R11-R9-R10 is a strange configuration since C7 will block any DC voltage. Some strange startup circutry?

Comment: microprocessor: 2840   9247   FADA AAC  102N3500

Comment: driving mosfets (left and middle on PCB): ST99231 P50N06 replace by me by IRFB4332

Comment: mosfet at right of PCB is for the fan : ST9A235  P50N06; all those original one probably prprietary Danfoss chips.

Comment: As per the site rules, all vital information should be edited into the original question and not scattered in the comments. MCU certainly makes things more difficult to analyze. That 18 pin IC, is that a MOSFET driver or an MCU?

Comment: I guess a MCU (has Xtal). Dont find specs on it. Danfoss numbers?

Comment: Can winding resistance be OK and coil still faulty? Can I switch both drains?

Comment: To see if the problem moves? But your gate drive is broken? Why are you not adressing that first? If you disconnect the MOSFETs or gate resistors, do you get the correct square-ish wave from both outputs with 12-15 V? If not, that uC is probably broken.

Comment: My gate signal was never higher than 8.5Vpp and only present at g2; When I disconnect both Rg's I do not have any signal anymore at both gatedriving pins at µP. (pin 5 and 6).

Comment: Looks like more in your oscillogram but non the less, my best guess is that the I/O driver inside the MCU is damaged. You could try to amplify the low output with a say 3.3 V input logic IC to drive the gate, but you have to consider your different options here as in getting a new unit or spare part.

Comment: Thanks for yr help!